# Загрузка видео-роликов и их просмотр на сайте без YouTube

Tags: php, видео, youtube, веб-служба, flash-player

На сайте необходимо реализовать загрузку видео-роликов и их просмотр. Ранее пользовались схемой: грузим на YouTube, вставляем код плеера на сайт. Однако стандартные ограничения YouTube не позволяют выполнять желаемого или быть может мы плохо знаем этот сервис?

**Вопрос:** Как на сайте организовать загрузку видео-роликов и их просмотр? Видео-ролики могут быть абсолютно разных разрешений и форматов. Иногда требуется обрезать в них куски - т.е. хорошо бы иметь возможность простейшего online-редактирования видео-ролика по части обрезки.

Может быть есть подобные YouTube пусть даже платные сервисы для таких задач со своим API?

Или же порекомендуете какие-нибудь готовые набор (конструкции, движки) для реализации такого функционала у себя на сайте?

Answer (score 1):

Отредактировать и запускать на сайте это разные вещи. Можно отредактировать на том же Youtube, на [wevideo.com](http://wevideo.com) или в какой то программе, а потом разместить на своем хостинге и запускать на сайте например с помощью популярного скрипта [Videojs](http://videojs.com/). Но файл видео предварительно нужно (или хотя бы желательно) конвертировать в MP4 (если он в другом формате) например на сайте [files-conversion.com](http://files-conversion.com) и WEBM например по ссылке [video.online-convert.com/convert-to-webm](http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-webm). Подключить можно вот так:

```
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video.min.js"></script>
<video controls autoplay loop>
 <source src="path/to/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"><!--Chrome-->
 <source src="path/to/myvideo.webm" type="video/webm"><!--Opera & FF-->
</video>
```

ps. Возможно немножко устарелая информация — давно не проверял что там у них поменялось